# mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card

Tags: mount

I have a problem trying to mount a SD card in Ubuntu 12.04. The message what I get from the system is:

```
mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
```

I'm on the `3.5.0-24-generic` kernel.

I check previous kernel 3.5.0-15 and card is on the system. I think is some bug in kernel.

I was looking some solution on web. They say my card is dead (but is working)

What I should do?

Some more information on this issue [here](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/coffee-lounge/191312-new-kernels-incompatible-some-sdcards.html). If someone have more question about my hardware just ask.

Comment: Can you please indicate your laptop's make and model? also if you could run `lspci -nn` and `lsusb` and add the output to your post it would be useful. This helps determine which card reader you may have and whether there is a known problem with that model.

Comment: I had a similar problem with a Sony laptop, quite a while ago. It would occasionally go to a state where it would give the exact same error to all SD cards. As a workaround I think reboot helped, but it was eventually fixed by a kernel upgrade. Would it be possible to try, say, Ubuntu 13.10 from a USB stick and see if this has been fixed? 13.10 has kernel 3.11.0.

Comment: If the problem presents itself with a specific kernel and with the previous not, then is a bug.

Comment: What does `mount -t vfat /dev/mmcblk0 /tmp` show? and any messages in `dmesg`?  Error sounds like a bad formatting. Try the bottom comment: http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/hardware/471033-sdhc-card-suddenly-inaccessible.html (testdisk to check the disc)

Comment: Bug fixed https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1158982 just upgrade your kernel

Answer (score 4):

Basically this error arises only when the SDcard got damaged. But as you mentioned its working, Please try the following steps and share your feedback.

- Please check the output of `dmesg` or `lsusb` to check whether it detects the SD card.
- Open the "Disk Utility" application and check whether your SD card is listed. If its listed, just click it -> Unmount Volume -> Format the Volume with suitable filesystem.
- Also, try mounting the SD card on Windows and check whether it is working or not.

Also, you can downgrade your kernel by installing the old kernel / latest stable kernel version with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get autoremove`.

`wget` the latest stable kernal from [Kernel Website](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) and install it with `sudo dpkg -i *.deb && sudo update-grub2`

Please select the proper kernel while booting and check whether your SD card mounts well!