# How do I get an SD card reader to work in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: drivers, 13.04, sd-card

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 on a CLEVO P151EMx, it has a built-in Realtek PCIE Cardreader 5289, which works fine in Windows, but refuses to show up in Ubuntu.

I can't see any sd cards I put in it in /dev, and lspci shows it as follows:

```
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5289 (rev 01)
```

I've tried the fix here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks/+bug/971876.
But no luck.

Any suggestions?

P.S. I'm trying to format a microSDHC card using fdisk for use in a BeagleBone Black, if that helps.

Someone asked for the output of lspci -v -s 03:00.0:

```
 03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5289 (rev 01)
 Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 5105<br>
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43<br>
 Memory at f7a00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]<br>
 Capabilities: access denied <br>
 Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
```

The relevant entries in dmesg -T are:

```
[Tue May 21 15:19:36 2013] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
[Tue May 21 15:19:37 2013] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
[Tue May 21 15:19:36 2013] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
```

Comment: I know this dosen't help, but I've had the same problems on numerous netbooks/laptops. The problem is that it dosen't show up as a standard ide device, so drivers must be written for specific implementations. I just ended up giving up and buying a $2 sd card reader from amazon.

Comment: I have Clevo W110ER with the same card reader. I needed this rts-bpp driver in Ubuntu 12.10 but in 13.04 it works out of the box. The driver in use is `rtsx_pci`. Show your `lspci -v -s 03:00.0`.

Comment: Thanks @ScottGoodgame, I'll probably end up buying one, this is getting really frustrating.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: @guntbert Uh..thanks? I figured since it was more relevant to the comments, I would put it here, but it's been added to the post anyway.

Comment: It seems you have module loaded for this device. What `dmesg -T` shows when you insert a card? Filter only relevant log entries by date please. Relevant log lines start with `mmc`. My card show up as `/dev/mmcblk0*`.

Comment: @Grzegorz Added the entries to the question

Comment: Same issue http://askubuntu.com/questions/256866/mmc0-error-110-whilst-initialising-sd-card and solution with patch http://talk.maemo.org/showthread.php?t=72789 That's all I can do.

Answer (score 1):

I tested ubuntu 13.10 on clevo w310CZ, with similar realtek's chipset (no 5289 but 5286)
sd card no mount too

and no one kernel module load

```
$ sudo lspci -v -s 03:00.0  
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5286 (rev 01)  Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 3110  
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11  
Memory at f7400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+  
Capabilities: [70] ExpressEndpoint, MSI 00  
Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=1 Masked- 
Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data  
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting  
Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel  
Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-01-00-4c-e0-00
```

I've tried to fix this bug :[Realtek Card Reader RTL8411 Device 5289 (PCI 03:00.0) Driver and udisks Rule](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks/+bug/971876).

worked on Ubuntu 12.04 but doesn't on 13.10

I posted a new Bug here [10ec:5286 [Clevo W310CZ] Realtek Card Reader not working](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks/+bug/1250605).